# Java HttpConnection

Tags: java, apache, http, server

I got an problem with my java server..
In development mode I have no errors but in the production mode always this error
occurs:

```
org.apache.http.ConnectionClosedException: Connection is closed
Okt 29 11:38:47 service.sh[506]: at org.apache.http.impl.nio.NHttpConnectionBase.assertNotClosed(NHttpConnectionBase.java:498)
Okt 29 11:38:47 service.sh[506]: at org.apache.http.impl.nio.DefaultNHttpServerConnection.submitResponse(DefaultNHttpServerConnection.java:340)
Okt 29 11:38:47 service.sh[506]: at org.apache.http.nio.protocol.HttpAsyncService.commitFinalResponse(HttpAsyncService.java:722)
Okt 29 11:38:47 service.sh[506]: at org.apache.http.nio.protocol.HttpAsyncService.exception(HttpAsyncService.java:309)
Okt 29 11:38:47 service.sh[506]: at org.apache.http.impl.nio.DefaultHttpServerIODispatch.onException(DefaultHttpServerIODispatch.java:153)
Okt 29 11:38:47 service.sh[506]: at org.apache.http.impl.nio.DefaultHttpServerIODispatch.onException(DefaultHttpServerIODispatch.java:52)
Okt 29 11:38:47 service.sh[506]: at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIODispatch.inputReady(AbstractIODispatch.java:125)
Okt 29 11:38:47 service.sh[506]: at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.readable(BaseIOReactor.java:162)
Okt 29 11:38:47 service.sh[506]: at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvent(AbstractIOReactor.java:337)
Okt 29 11:38:47 service.sh[506]: at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvents(AbstractIOReactor.java:315)
Okt 29 11:38:47 service.sh[506]: at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(AbstractIOReactor.java:276)
Okt 29 11:38:47 service.sh[506]: at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIOReactor.java:104)
Okt 29 11:38:47 service.sh[506]: at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor$Worker.run(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:588)
```

I dont know why this error occurs. Maybe someone of you has an idea?

Comment: Is the connection being closed by RST or FIN packets?  And from which process did said packets originate?  (If you're not sure, you can check using your favourite network analysis tool.)

Comment: I'd suggest to check keepalive param http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#keepalive

Comment: its closed by FIN packets